# random_bytes_engine generates same key over and over again

Tags: c++

For some reason the function below keeps generating same key over and over again, no matter what. Why is that happening? How can I solve that?

```cpp
uint8_t key[32];
encryption::generate_random_key(key);

...

template <size_t N>
void generate_random_key(uint8_t(&iv_buff)[N])
{
    using random_bytes_engine = std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, size_t>;
    random_bytes_engine rbe;

    std::generate(std::begin(iv_buff), std::end(iv_buff), [&rbe]() {
        return static_cast<uint8_t>(rbe());
    });
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `std::string` be a better container here? Or at least `std::vector<uint8_t>`?

Comment: You're not seeding your engine, so it is always created with the same default state.

Comment: Making an alias for "random bytes engine" and using it once is really kind of pointless.

Comment: Seems like so, I'm open for recommendations.

Comment: How do I seed the engine?

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeding the engine and it gives you all the same each time from the its default state. However, for the encryption key generation it is better to use solely `std::random_device` or any specialized function from libraries like OpenSSL. Otherwise, if you are ok with key generated from a pseudo-random bytes, use `std::random_device` to generate seed for the pseudo-random generator (like `std::mt19937`).

Comment: Could you write an example with it?

Comment: @nop Did you try looking at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/independent_bits_engine), or any examples?

Comment: @super, yes and I don't know how to use it with std::generate, because I need I'm returning a reference of the key afterwards.

Comment: @nop There's nothing wrong with your `std::genereate` usage. You are just not seeding the enginge, as pointed out in the comments and this answer. The link I gave you clearly shows that you can seed the engine by passing a value to the constructor or using `rbe.seed`. Also any example you find on the internet will tell you this.

Comment: `error C2039: 'generate': is not a member of 'std::random_device'` https://pastebin.com/3KJ9rnxs

Comment: The last one looks mostly good, only one question - why ` dist(0, 1024)` ? unsigned byte value range is from 0 to 255. So it can be ` dist(0, 255)`.